# Angular Signals: What's the proper way to trigger a fetch when input Signals change value?

Tags: angular, typescript, components, angular-signals

So I've been learning and using **Signals** in Angular, and it's exciting. However, there are some use cases where I feel there's some friction. I can't figure out a good pattern when you have a component with `input signals`, and you want to trigger a re-fetch of data whenever some input value changes.

`computed` is obviously not the way to go since they can't be async. And `effect`, according to the docs, shouldn't modify component state. So that seems like a no-go as well. And ngOnChanges is being deprecated (long term) in favor of Signals-based components and zoneless.

Consider the following component:

```
@Component()
export class ChartComponent {
    dataSeriesId = input.required<string>();
    fromDate = input.required<Date>();
    toDate = input.required<Date>();

    private data = signal<ChartData | null>(null);
}
```

Whenever one of the input signals gets a new value, I want to trigger a re-fetch of data, and `update` the value of the private `data` signal.

How would one go about this? What's the best practice? Effect and bypass the rule to modify state?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I use Angular's `rxjs-interop` to convert the id input signal to an `Observable`, then `switchMap` to fetch the results and then convert the result back to a signal, like this:

```js
import { toObservable, toSignal } from '@angular/core/rxjs-interop';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-chart',
  standalone: true,
  template: `
    {{data()}}
  `,
})
export class ChartComponent {
  dataSeriesId = input.required<string>();
  data = toSignal(
    toObservable(this.dataSeriesId).pipe(switchMap((id) => this.fetchData(id))),
    {
      initialValue: null,
    }
  );

  private fetchData(id: string) {
    return of('Example data for id ' + id).pipe(delay(1000));
  }
}
```

Working example on [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-epzd98?file=src%2Fmain.ts)

Comment: Interesting! switchMap is a bit mindbending for me but I can see why/how it works. What if you have three input signals that should all trigger the fetch?

Comment: In that case you would convert all of the signals to observables and use the `combineLatest` operator the get the latest params each time any of the signals change. 
Example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-u3qyeg?file=src%2Fmain.ts

Comment: I agree RxJS can be hard. But I do recommend it for asynchronous data loading. The switchMap operator is extremely useful in your situation as it will cancel any data fetching operation that is still running if a new dataSeriesId comes in. This is good for performance, but also for data integrity. If you simply use a signal effect to fetch the data you risk showing the wrong data because an old fetching operation may complete *after* a newer one.